# Printing array of u8 in Linux Kernel as Hex

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, printk

I am trying to print the following variables in my custom Linux Kernel Module for debugging purposes:

```
__le16 length; // The length of the data
u8 data[128];
```

The `data` variable has a maximum length of 128 bytes but we might not use all if it. The length variable determines how much we used of the `data` variable. I want to print the content of `data` variable in Hex format. I am doing so using a for loop however, the following code prints each byte in a separate line when I inspect the logs using `dmesg`. I suppose this is because of the mechanism of how `printk` works. I can still print the content in the same line but as string using `%s`. However, I want to print all the bytes in the same line in Hex format. How can I do that?

```
u8 i = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
{
    printk("0x%02x ", data[i]);
}
printk("\n");
```

Comment: There are two approaches: `%*ph` specifier (up to 64 bytes to dump at once) and `print_hex_dump()`. Use one which is suitable. So, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164581/2511795